# Insert multiple rows, into multiple tables, including junction

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have 3 tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "source" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "foo" VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);
CREATE TABLE "destination" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "foo" VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);
CREATE TABLE "source_destination" ( -- source,destination n:m junction table
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "source_id" INTEGER REFERENCES "source"("id"),
  "destination_id" INTEGER REFERENCES "destination"("id")
);
```

`source` has some data `foo` I'm migrating to `destination` to enable `source` to have many `foo`s. `destination` may also have many `source`s (so many-to-many relationship), but the original data is 1:1. (later we'll be able to drop `foo` from `source`, but it's not relevant now)

I'm trying to, for each row in `source`, create a matching row in `destination`, and associate them via `source_destination`.

I tried:

```sql
WITH
insert_destination AS (
  INSERT INTO "destination" (
    "foo"
  )
  SELECT
    "source"."foo" -- error here
  RETURNING "destination"."id"
),
insert_source_destination AS (
  INSERT INTO "source_destination" (
    "source_id",
    "destination_id"
  )
  SELECT
    insert_destination,
    "source"."id"
  FROM "source"
  RETURNING "source_destination"."id"
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM insert_source_destination;
```

but got:

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "source"

I tried:

```sql
WITH
insert_source_destination AS (
  INSERT INTO "source_destination" (
    "source_id",
    "destination_id"
  )
  SELECT
    (
      INSERT INTO "destination" ( -- error here
        "foo"
      )
      SELECT
        "source"."foo"
      RETURNING "destination"."id"
    ),
    "source"."id"
  FROM "source"
  RETURNING "source_destination"."id"
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM insert_source_destination;
```

but got:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO"

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You are really missing FROM "source" in your first INSERT ... SELECT.

Comment: @CetinBasoz wouldn't that mean that `insert_destination` and `insert_source_destination` work on potentially different charges? I need `source_destination` to have the correct `source_id`

Comment: Nope but your returning is also wrong. Anyway I wıll add a simpler approach.

Comment: BTW, I assume you already thought about what is the point of doing this. (and those double quotes are too much, don't you think, when you are not using casing for the field names).

Comment: I also edited my reply to have your SQL revised.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach:

```
INSERT INTO "destination" ( "foo"  )
  SELECT "foo" from "source";

insert into insert_source_destination ("source_id", "destination_id")
select s."id", d."id"
  from "source" s
  inner join "destination" d on s."foo" = d."foo";

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM insert_source_destination;
```

EDIT: Your SQL edited (no idea on purpose):

```
WITH
insert_destination AS (
  INSERT INTO "destination" (
    "foo"
  )
  SELECT
    "foo" -- error here
  from "source"
  RETURNING *
),
insert_source_destination AS (
  INSERT INTO "source_destination" (
    "source_id",
    "destination_id"
  )
  SELECT
    "source"."id",
    d.id
  FROM insert_destination d
    inner join "source" on "source"."id" = d."id"
  returning *
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM insert_source_destination;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OjUpQjwX)

EDIT: I made a typo saying id instead of foo:

```
WITH
insert_destination AS (
  INSERT INTO "destination" (
    "foo"
  )
  SELECT
    "foo" -- error here
  from "source"
  RETURNING *
),
insert_source_destination AS (
  INSERT INTO "source_destination" (
    "source_id",
    "destination_id"
  )
  SELECT
    "source"."id",
    d.id
  FROM insert_destination d
    inner join "source" on "source"."foo" = d."foo"
  returning *
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM insert_source_destination;
```

[DBfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8YlgyfpN)

It does make sense to use foo, since that is what you want to do in your original post. If it is not the case, would you share sample data and expected result (and why the need for intermediate table).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `join "destination" d on s."foo" = d."foo"` because: it's non-unique, and because in the real case (not mcve) I'm actually migrating multiple columns, some from a table joined with `source`.

Comment: `inner join "source" on "source"."id" = d."id"` - but why would `source.id` be equal `d.id` if `source` for example `source` has more than data than `destination` before running this query?

Comment: @IvanRubinson, my bad. It would be foo (thought foo wrote id, sorry).